# Querying from a hierarchical path

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, path, hierarchy

I have a column in a table that has a fields like this:

```
Product Sales\Margin\SYSTEMS OPERATIONS\Systems Operations Expenses\Cost of Sales\Margin\TOTAL MARGIN\OPERATING INCOME\Pre-Tax Income\Net Income from Continuing Operations\Income B4 Extraordinary Items\NET INCOME
```

another example

```
Lease Operations COGS\Lease Operations Expense\Margin\TOTAL MARGIN\OPERATING INCOME\Pre-Tax Income\Net Income from Continuing Operations\Income B4 Extraordinary Items\NET INCOME
```

Everything leads back to Net Income, right?

I have accounts that may be in four different sub categories, all of which belong to a category that belongs to Net Income, eventually.

**Problem:** There are, for example, four categories, all called "Salaries & Wages" each which belong to a different parent category.

**Question:** How can I query for the sum of all accounts that eventually lead into net income?

***Or***, how could I query for all the accounts that belong to "System operations", or "Lease Operations"?

Let me know what clarification is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL (as with most competing RDBMS products) is terrible at efficiently manipulating hierarchical data represented using this model (known as "path enumeration").  You would be wise to look into remodelling your data using either the "nested sets" or "transitive closure" models.

Comment: @eggyal thanks bud, one of my higher ups asked me to "delimit" it this way.. it looked to me, with my limited RDBMS knowledge, that it was going to be a disaster and wanted to use a table with a parent-child relationship. I'm going to look into these models to see how I could apply it to our data and maybe make a reccomendation to change the structure.